# Scope problem - Nested $mdDialog within class based controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, es6-class, angularjs-material

I am moving my AngularJS controllers over to a class based model in order to support a few newer ideas that have come up lately. This has brought up an issue using AngularJS Materials $mdDialog service that I'm having trouble with.

I have a setup where a parent dialog is opened, and another performs a confirmation step when a user wants to undo any changes they've made.

**Parent dialog Code:**

```
// Expand item data
expandItem(data, ev){
  this._mdDialog.show({
    controller: 'expandCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'ec',
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template',
    parent: angular.element( document.body ),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose: true,
    locals: { 
      data: {
        asset: data,
        table: this.selectTable
      }}
  }).then(rowData => {
  }, function(){});
}
```

**Nested dialog Code:**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
class expandCtrl {

  constructor($mdDialog, data) {
    this.itemData = data;
    this.itemStateCapture = angular.copy(this.itemData);
    this._mdDialog = $mdDialog;
  }

  // Cancel edits and revert item back to its previous state
  cancelEdits(ev) {

    let cancelConfirm = this._mdDialog.confirm()
    .multiple(true)
    .title('Are you sure?')
    .textContent('Really cancel all edits and revert this item back to its original state?')
    .ariaLabel('Edit cancel confirmation')
    .targetEvent(ev)
    .ok('Cancel Edits!')
    .cancel('Go Back');

    this._mdDialog.show(cancelConfirm).then(function() {

      //**************************//
      //**** The Problem Line ****//
      //**************************//
      this.itemData = this.itemStateCapture;

    }, function() {});
  }
}
// Init Controller
angular.module('dbProject').controller('expandCtrl', expandCtrl);

})();
```

I need to have the top level **this.itemData** variable be rewritten inside of the **this._mdDialog.show()** line. There appears to be a scoping problem though, and nothing I've tried successfully accesses that variable. I have tried injecting $scope, redirecting to an outside function, even accessing the data through angular.element().controller(), but I haven't made any headway.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It appears the issue is as I suspected - $mdDialog.show() creates it's own scope. I have a few ideas to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up converting my controller to a hybrid sort of approach, and including $scope. $mdDialog seems to not function well without it (Though I would love to be proven wrong).

See below:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myProject')
    .controller('expandCtrl', expandCtrl);

    expandCtrl.$inject = [
      '$mdDialog',
      '$timeout',
      '$scope',
      'data',
      'uaService',
      'dataService'
    ];

    function expandCtrl($mdDialog, $timeout, $scope, data, uaService, dataService){
      // Submit edits functionality
      this.submitEdits = function(table, access, data, ev){
        let confirmSubmit = $mdDialog.confirm()
        .multiple(true)
        .title('Are you sure?')
        .textContent('Really submit these changes?')
        .ariaLabel('Submit confirmation')
        .targetEvent(ev)
        .ok('Submit!')
        .cancel('Go Back');

        $mdDialog.show(confirmSubmit).then(function() {

            let editData = {
                table: $scope.table,
                data: $scope.itemData,
                prevData: $scope.itemStateCapture
            }

            dataService.submitEdits(editData)
            .then(res =>{
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(e =>{console.error(e)})

        }, function() {});
    }
  }
})();
```